# How to code colors in hex

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, graphical-output

[Hexagonal tessellations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_tiling), or tilings of the plane, are three-colorable -- meaning that using only three colors, such as Red, Blue, and Green, every hexagon can be colored without any two hexagons that share a border sharing a color. [A partial example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3N71.gif) showing such a pattern.

Given a partial hexagonal tiling in ASCII (via STDIN, reading from a file, etc.), change the characters' colors (via ANSI codes, image manipulation, etc.) to fit this coloring. The twist is the middle of the hexagons (the `*`, below) are the three colors, and the lines between need to be a mix of their two corresponding hex's `*` colors. If the line is on the outside border, it should match the corresponding `*`.

For example, given the partial hexagonal tiling of

```
 / \ / \ / \ / \
| * | * | * | * |
 \ / \ / \ / \ /
  | * | * | * |
   \ / \ / \ /
```

suppose we decide to color the top-left hex `*` to be Red, and its two neighbors to be Blue and Green (going clockwise). Then the `|` line needs to be Magenta and the `/` line needs to be Yellow. If we keep coloring, we'll eventually end up with something like this (enlarged for clarity):

[image: Hexagonal Coloring 1]

Or, for an input of

```
     / \
    | * |
   / \ /
  | * |
 / \ /
| * |
 \ /
```

you might color it like so (enlarged for clarity):

[image: Hexagonal Coloring 2]

A few additional test cases (your code should be able to handle these):

```
 / \ / \
| * | * |
 \ / \ /
  | * |
 / \ / \
| * | * |
 \ / \ /


 / \
| * |
 \ / \
  | * |
 / \ /
| * |
 \ /



 / \
| * |
 \ /
```

### Rules

- The input is guaranteed to have at least one hexagon, and no input will have a "hole."
- You don't need to start your coloring with Red, so long as you maintain the three-color rule.
- If the partial tiling can be two-colored, you can do so without penalty (such as in the second example) - you don't necessarily need to extrapolate the partial tiling to a full tiling.
- The hexagon centers `*` must be colored with either Red, Blue, or Green, while the lines between must be either Cyan, Yellow, or Magenta. For example, having a Magenta `*` is not allowed, and a Red `|` or `\` or `/` must be on the outside border of the drawing. See *Colors*, below.
- If your console doesn't have these exact colors, please use the closest approximation and specify in your answer what approximation you're using.
- Leading or trailing whitespace, including trailing newlines, are acceptable so long as the characters line up.
- The partial tiling can be input with space-padding to form a rectangle, if that makes it easier for your code.
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable. If a function, you can return the output rather than printing it.
- Output can be to the console, saved as an image, etc.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

#### Colors and Color Mixtures:

The three available base colors are (with color codes in RGB decimal format):

- Red `(255,0,0)`
- Green `(0,255,0)`
- Blue `(0,0,255)`

The combinations are:

- Red and Green combine to make Yellow `(255,255,0)`
- Blue and Green combine to make Cyan `(0,255,255)`
- Red and Blue combine to make Magenta `(255,0,255)`

Comment: Can you add a test case with a hole please? Like the first (additional) one, but without the middle `*`

Comment: If extra whitespace is given at the end of lines or newlines at the end of the input, do they have to be preserved?

Comment: @H.PWiz Such a situation would never arise. No need to worry about it.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino No, that's purely your decision. Input/output whitespace formatting isn't the interesting part of this challenge.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. Also, will we ever have to handle empty input?

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Nope, you're guaranteed at least one hex in the input. I'll clarify.

Answer (score 7):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>219</s> <s>203</s> 201 bytes

```js
f=
s=>s.split`
`.map((b,i,a)=>b.replace(/./g,(c,j)=>`<font color=#${g=(x,y)=>((a[x+i]||``)[b=y+j]==`*`&&15<<b%3*4)|(y<0?8<<9:g(x,y-2)),(g(0,2)|g(-1,1)|g(1,1)).toString(16).slice(1)}>${c}</font>`)).join`
`
```

```html
<input type=button value="Colourise!" onclick=i.innerHTML=f(i.textContent)>
<pre id=i contenteditable> / \ / \
| * | * |
 \ / \ / \
  | * | * |
 / \ / \ / \
| * |   | * |
 \ / \ / \ / \
  | * | * | * |
 / \ / \ / \ /
| * | * |
 \ / \ /</pre>
```

Explanation: Each character is wrapped in a `font` tag to set its colour, which is calculated by checking each square, plus the squares two to the left and right, plus the four squares one away diagonally, for `*`s and if so combining the colours of all `*`s found. The `*` colours are chosen simply by taking their horizontal coordinate modulo 3 and shifting a bitmask appropriately. Edit: Saved 2 bytes by switching from `#RRGGBB` to `#RGB` colours.

Comment: You don't need to handle inner holes, if that makes a difference.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork No, I was just showing off.

Comment: "Colourise!" - You spelled this wrong.

Comment: @OldBunny2800 It's spelt correctly in my language...

Comment: @OldBunny2800 American isn't the only spelling-set that exists. There's British (a superset of English English), Australian (which for some reason includes New Zealand - perhaps it should be called Australasian) and Canadian (that place north of the majority of the USA), for instance.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I'm dying. Thank you for that laugh.

Comment: I think you can remove the `#` from the colour specification to save a byte. You might also be able to (ab)use html's high tolerance for colour values to save some more bytes...

Comment: @Luke Removing the `#` doesn't seem to work, but you inspired me to switch to `#RGB` colour values to save two bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 210 bytes (using HTML + CSS)

Similar to my [canvas approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/147064/47097); locates all the `*`s in the input string and writes hexagons to the page in the form of absolutely positioned `<pre>` elements. Because `mix-blend-mode` is set to `lighten`, color addition is performed automatically when characters overlap.

```
s=>s.split`
`.map((r,y)=>[...r].map((c,x)=>c=='*'&&document.write(`<pre style=position:fixed;mix-blend-mode:lighten;line-height:1;left:${x}ch;top:${y}em;color:${['red','lime','blue'][x%3]}> / \\
| * |
 \\ /`)))
```

```js
f=

s=>s.split`
`.map((r,y)=>[...r].map((c,x)=>c=='*'&&document.write(`<pre style=position:fixed;mix-blend-mode:lighten;line-height:1;left:${x}ch;top:${y}em;color:${['red','lime','blue'][x%3]}> / \\
| * |
 \\ /`)))

f(` / \\ / \\ / \\ / \\
| * | * | * | * |
 \\ / \\ / \\ / \\ /
  | * | * | * |
   \\ / \\ / \\ /`)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 279 bytes

```python
e=enumerate
x=input()
c=[[i,j]for i,t in e(x)for j,_ in e(t)if"*"==x[i][j]]
C=[[j%3*([i,j]in c)for j,_ in e(o)]for i,o in e(x)]
for J,K in c:
	for i in-1,0,1:q=2-(i&1);_=C[i+J];_[K+q]=_[K-q]=_[K-q]|C[J][K]
for i,o in e(x):print"".join("[%dm"%(30+C[i][j])+x[i][j]for j,_ in e(o))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVDLioMwFF1PfmE2IeCQaLS13VmycqefkAYRjUykJtZGcKD/7viawXZxuZx7Hjmk/bHfRp/GUlZQ6ba3mESdtH2nYZO3@KYelppWaoyChQ6sMogEncxLTIJHe1MWo6tGhIySSd03ssutBAPbwkDBOFe0FpXpoKJ2egRKPJAZ1jRboSWqQi5ibOBK8FoIEE@u2jm7ePFOouLVYcgWaP4CBZgPCU3nQxGBj4WfgB/SIw2jOzv5WH2F5JKxmCsvEZeMp95dsGn5/@sZ80TwdE3bxUdtp7RFKKiNmj7jkztlgxx8Pnrx2pl4W/m3nmQc4QFe9wOe0IUvA14F8ADguwDu6V8)

Golfed and fixed thanks to user202729!
-27 bytes thanks to Mr. Xcoder
-24 bytes thanks to Jonathan Frech

Comment: [337 bytes](https://tio.run/##dU/BbsIwDD3Tr7AiVUoglLLeQDnxGSWHDNLhUtKSpBqT@PcuKaDBtB2c@Nl@9nvdlz@0phiGva6goheuhTb9SVvlNVslk50oS@S1rFoLyD2gAU0vLMI6AqvMh6aNNtQzhhWZEiEuJcqylnK9CeQ6LaZ0XBGmd38RW8bu69vHeplMYuUY8S6oGBEGNF/ynC9XZ/E2V@@OIlvjTBzLXK6t2JQxkeFdxttRRExnZ3kV9gfPR5xMrPa9NWRrSFa3aCh5/Nu8KMp0f0odSWmRzzY3O/xu6x8L7JcFNnyiP0DbhTbJ0HS9zzy2hAOxhIFyUGGjgzd3UJ12IKBB5@lJdTQmfGxnVqs9ZZnrGvQ0ag2HonTXNz5QKnpjh1pn0Xh667ABFrB9juQKU3iJ5HUAFgn8HoDn9jc).

Comment: Also `2-abs(i)` is `2-(i&1)` in this context, 336 bytes.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Cool, thanks!

Comment: I think `\033` can be `\33` (saving one byte) or the actual `\x1b` character ([saving three bytes](https://tio.run/##dZDBboMwDIbPyyvsEkViSiil0N5AOfUx0mhCNGymkNAQJCb13VlgTGqr7eDEX2z/v5zuy30avZ/OqsKgu8FRllnlBqtxW3S0gd5FplOakngpxw4MYbFVxZmyuO8acJScNGFsUlzpoVW2cCof@SqGSi4ERLWsjMUQOW@CFR3ZjPUMttAfijbewTEGFQkJ56MAKWop86MfroNDSBcJ313@NWgYW@XNr7xE88NlxjJDL0vVwzaNkijNrny/pfCWshw2/CISmVt@FHMi/Zl643fP4K8FN1d543aF7QLoyS/rLGhHSFwb8H/1KoJzG/QkoIdkc/zZJlq3@mcDNk14h0/3gW44xA@BHhvwDuHnBnxf/gY)).

Comment: [298 bytes](https://tio.run/##XZDBjsIgEIbPyyvshZB0AxVrq7c2nHwMJMYojVMtIKWJm/juXVq7iXoY4GP@@YfB/YazNevhpGsMxvWBstLr0HuD24OjV@gCt04bSrIpnQWwhGVeH06UZZ27QqBkZwhjgxba9K32h6Cru5jN0FFICbxRtfUYeIhNsKZ3NmLD908MDGqSEiHuEpRslKq2sapJNimdaqPo@F5h2Wxo/w0VGi8uIx5L9DVlIywLnvOivIn1ksJPwSpYiIvMVeXFVo4HFdcidtxHhrhNuLiph/AzLCdAH/1K58EEQrLGQvydb5mc2qQjCd3ki@1zDD6P8/l0Ngx4hXevgR44xW@B3gV4hfCnAL@m/wA).

Comment: @JonathanFrech oh cool, thanks! :D

Comment: Line 1: e,x=enumerate,input()

Comment: @OldBunny2800 I think that's the same length. You swap two `=` and a `;` for two `,` and a `=`.

Comment: Yeah, you're right.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>346</s> 331 bytes

```python
e=enumerate
C='0132645'
def f(s):
 c={(i,j):[1+(i/2%2+j/4)%3*2]for i,l in e(s)for j,x in e(l)if'*'==x}
 for i,l in e(s):
  r=''
  for j,x in e(l):a=c.get((i,j),c.get((i-(x<'|'),j+[-1,1][x>'/']+(x>'z')),[]))+c.get((i+(x<'|'),j+[1,-1][x>'/']-(x>'z')),[])if' '<x else[0];r+='\033[3'+C[[sum(a)/len(a),6][set(a)=={5,1}]]+'m'+x
  print r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY/BbsIwDIbveQoLCTkhKSUtcOjILjxGmkMF6ZaqlKotUjfg2buwiYn2YP229fm3XX91n@cqGgarbHU52SbrLNkrXMk42q43SI42h5y2LCFwUFfqRMESLTl1YTSPeBGu2TxeRCY/N@BECa4C6@lHWYj@ryyZy3GBSvV3AhPQ20KjEL1MZpJMHZYftqO/O8UzD2i/wxsyUXAdSCGN7t8xRMOp129kTGjDGH/i/AWXIvjHg1fcnwe468GWrdUr89ZwhekqjnWMfK91eznRjIWlrbyIrdGtt86YUteNkHdjOJ6Q9/6DunFVB82Q09lsRiCEdBTkBgsYBZkQIXiXMfXojAgAb65lYpZtXbqOYlr5N4Yf)

Answer (score 1):

## HTML (Canvas) + JavaScript (ES6), 13 + 251 = 264 bytes

Locates all the `*`s in the input string and paints an ASCII hexagon on the canvas at the corresponding positions. Because `globalCompositeOperation='lighter'`, color addition is performed automatically when characters overlap.

#### HTML

```
<canvas id=c>
```

#### JavaScript

```
s=>{c.width=c.height=s.length
with(c.getContext`2d`)font='1px monospace',globalCompositeOperation='lighter',s.split`
`.map((r,y)=>[...r].map((c,x)=>c=='*'&&[` / \\`,`| * |`,` \\ /`].map((t,i)=>fillText(t,x,y+i),fillStyle=['red','lime','blue'][x%3])))}
```

---

A multiplier and additional `scale()` command were added to the snippet for visibility.

```js
// Unscaled
/*
f=
s=>{c.width=c.height=s.length
with(c.getContext`2d`)font='1px monospace',globalCompositeOperation='lighter',s.split`
`.map((r,y)=>[...r].map((c,x)=>c=='*'&&[` / \\`,`| * |`,` \\ /`].map((t,i)=>fillText(t,x,y+i),fillStyle=['red','lime','blue'][x%3])))}
*/


// Scaled
let scaleFactor = 40

f=
s=>{c.width=c.height=s.length*scaleFactor
with(c.getContext`2d`)scale(scaleFactor,scaleFactor),font='1px monospace',globalCompositeOperation='lighter',s.split`
`.map((r,y)=>[...r].map((c,x)=>c=='*'&&[` / \\`,`| * |`,` \\ /`].map((t,i)=>fillText(t,x,y+i),fillStyle=['red','lime','blue'][x%3])))}


// Test
f(` / \\ / \\ / \\ / \\
| * | * | * | * |
 \\ / \\ / \\ / \\ /
  | * | * | * |
   \\ / \\ / \\ /`)
```

```html
<canvas id=c>
```

[image]

---

Also see my [CSS-based approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/147066/47097).

Comment: I don't believe this meets the required output:
 [https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pp3J0.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pp3J0.png). The forward and backslashes are supposed to be the additive combinations of the colors of the hexagons they border, not separate.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Hmm, looks to be an issue with inconsistent font widths (the positions are correct on my computer). I'll look into this later today.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize there was a platform that was correct. If you update your answer with a screenshot, I'll revert my vote. Answers only need to work on at least one implementation, they don't need to be cross-platform.

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB/[Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 223 bytes

```matlab
a=input('')';s=size(a);p=zeros([s 3]);[i,j]=ind2sub(s,find(a=='*'));
for f=1:nnz(i)
p((-2:2)+i(f),(-1:1)+j(f),mod(f+~mod(j(f)/2,2),3)+1)=1;end
for f=1:nnz(a)
[i,j]=ind2sub(s,f);text(i/s(1),1-j/s(2),a(i,j),'Co',p(i,j,:));end
```

In slightly neater code format:

```matlab
a=input('')';                  %Grab input as 2D array
s=size(a);                     %Get input size
p=zeros([s 3]);                %Make empty colour matrix of matching size with RGB
[i,j]=ind2sub(s,find(a=='*')); %Find all *'s
for f=1:nnz(i)                 %For each *
    %Fill a 5x3 box centred at the * on the colour channel for this box
    %Overlapping regions between boxes will result in the correct mix.
    p((-2:2)+i(f),(-1:1)+j(f),mod(f+~mod(j(f)/2,2),3)+1)=1;
end
%Display as text on a figure
for f=1:nnz(a)
    [i,j]=ind2sub(s,f);
    text(i/s(1),1-j/s(2),a(i,j),'Co',p(i,j,:))
end
```

The input is taken as a 2D array, such as entering the following when prompted for input:

```matlab
[' / \ / \ / \ / \ ';'| * | * | * | * |';' \ / \ / \ / \ / ';'  | * | * | * |  ';'   \ / \ / \ /   ']
```

MATLAB so far as I'm aware doesn't have the ability to output colours to the console (except for dirty Java hacks which I am discounting). As such the output is instead printed to a figure.

Colouring is achieved by finding the location of all `*`'s in the input, and then in an RGB colour array (`p`), a 5x3 box of 1's (255 in MATLAB colour representation) are written centred about the `*`. The box is written to the colour corresponding with the mod-3 index along each line, with even lines having the colour index shifted by an offset.

This produces a colour matrix where any boxes that overlap will result in the required mixed colour. The example above produces the following colour matrix.

[image: Colour Matrix Example]

The white and black regions are irrelevant because at those locations a space is printed meaning we don't actually see the incorrect colour.

Once the colour matrix is created, we display each character on a figure using the `text` command, setting the colour of the text to the corresponding entry in the colour matrix. The above example will display:

[image: Sample Output]